# Need to edit 2 fields in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments

My theme says this above comments:

Leave a Reply

Your email address will not be published.

I want to edit both these words to something else, but when I look through all files, none of these words are coming back, so am unsure how to edit or even find.

Is there a code I can put in functions or something which can change these.

```
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">

<span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: why do you ask the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516438/label-for-authorname-label-how-to-edit

Comment: Different question... but thanks for -1. hope you feel all fuzzy and warm inside now...

Comment: I believe everything you have asked on multiple posts can be found on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form and this page has been mentioned multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Search the inputs in `comments.php` template.

Find this and edit.

Comment: How do I do that? These words are not inside comments.php

Comment: What theme you use? Possible are in theme options, or not, its depends of the theme.

Comment: I am using a theme called Easy By D5 Creation

Comment: Maybe if you put some code of `single.php`, i will help you. This is a premium theme, i can download that.

Answer (score 0):

What theme are you using? Most themes make a call to the function comment_form(), usually as an action... something like:

```
do_action('comment_form', $post->ID);
```

Usually, this will be in the comments.php file, in your theme's directory. You can add code to modify your theme's comment form in your functions file. Here is the reference in the codex, with an example:

[Function Reference/comment form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

Comment: I am using a theme called Easy By D5 Creation